# How can I preserve the EncryptByPassPhrase returned value inside a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

If you run this query:

```
  SELECT rnd, rnd FROM (
     SELECT RAND() AS rnd
  ) AS randvalues;
```

you will get same value in both rnd result columns, but if you run:

```
  SELECT pass, pass FROM (
     SELECT EncryptByPassPhrase('password','data') AS pass
  ) AS passvalues;
```

you will get two different values for pass columns.
Why? How can I preserve the first retrieved value for each row inside a subquery?

Comment: `RAND()` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to only me return the same value, so you should not expect otherwise: *"Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results.

For one connection, if RAND() is called with a specified seed value, all subsequent calls of RAND() produce results based on the seeded RAND() call."*

Comment: It's TripleDES. So long as `select cast(DecryptByPassphrase('password', pass) as varchar(10))` returns the same plaintext for both inputs... does it matter?

Comment: Obligatory comment that SQL Server is completely unsupported, and has been for ~2.5 years. It is long past time you sorted you upgrade path.